# Difference in execution of left-shift between literal constant and variable with same value

Tags: c, types, bit-manipulation

I am writing a C function which takes a parameter n and returns an int with bit representation of n 1's followed by enough 0's to fill the datatype (32 bits total). My code currently looks like this:

```
int upperBits(int n) {
    int retval = 0 - 1;
    int shift = 32 - n;
    retval = retval << shift;
    return retval;
}
```

This code fails when n=0, giving a return value of -1, represented by 32 1's, instead of 0. When, however, I replace shift with a literal:

```
int upperBits(int n) {
    int retval = 0 - 1;
    int shift = 32 - n;
    retval = retval << 32;
    return retval;
}
```

The code works properly, returning 0. I have used print statements to verify that shift = 32 when the function is called with n = 0, so I do not understand why these behave differently. What causes this difference, and how can I circumvent it?

If it is relevant, the code is running on a Linux machine and is compiled with gcc. I am required to use straightline code with only these operators: `!` `˜` `&` `ˆ` `|` `+` `<<` `>>`

EDIT: 
I still do not know exactly what the problem is, or an elegant solution, but this workaround is effective:

```
int upperBits(int n) {
        int retval = 0 - 1;
        int shift = 32 - n;
        int isnull = !(n);
        printf ("%x %x %x \n", retval, shift, n);
        retval = retval << (shift - isnull);
        retval = retval << isnull;
        printf ("%x %x %x \n", retval, shift, n);
        return retval;
}
```

Comment: In the first fragment, when `n==0`, you are shifting by 32; that's undefined behaviour if `int` is a 32-bit type as it usually is.  The second fragment, the left shift by 32 is simply undefined behaviour.  Note that `int retval = 0 - 1;` is normally written `int retval = -1;`.

Comment: The difference is caused by GCC taking an annoying interpretation of UB, which it does whenever it has the chance.

Answer (score 5):

You're performing an illegal left-shift.

Left shifting a negative number invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as does shifting by an amount greater than or equal to the bit width of the type in question.

Section 6.5.7 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding Bitwise Shift operators states:

> *3* The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands.  The type of the result is that  of  the  promoted  left  operand.   **If 
>   the  value  of  the  right  operand  is  negative  or  is greater than
>   or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is
>   undefined.**
>
> *4* The  result  of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit  positions; 
>   vacated  bits  are  filled  with zeros.  If E1 has  an  unsigned 
>   type,  the  value  of  the  result  is E1 × 2 E2 , reduced  modulo one
>   more  than  the  maximum  value  representable  in  the  result  type.
>   **If E1 has  a  signed type  and  nonnegative  value,  and E1 × 2 E2 is 
>   representable  in  the  result  type,  then  that  is the resulting
>   value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**

You can correct this by using unsigned types and by checking the size of the shift:

```
uint32_t upperBits(int n) {
    uint32_t retval = 0xffffffff;
    if (n <= 0 || n > 32) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        int shift = 32 - n;
        retval = retval << shift;
        return retval;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the information! I am required to use straightline programing (meaning no control statements like if), the function must return a signed int, and the input is always in range 0 <= n <= 32. Casting, explicit or implicit, is also forbidden. Is there a workaround with these restrictions?

Comment: @RyanJensen In that case your requirements are flawed, as they don't understand the ramifications of what they're asking for.